# Android Architecture Blueprints "todo‑mvp‑dagger", where is @Provides for TasksRepository?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger

Looking at the Android Architecture Blueprints "todo‑mvp‑dagger" from here: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture.

I'm trying to understand the Dagger2 implementation and I can't seem to figure out how they are getting Dagger2 to provide the TasksRepository.

They have `@Provides` for "provideTasksLocalDataSource" and "provideTasksRemoteDataSource" but where is the one for the actual TaskRepository?

In the TodoApplication class they have this:

```
@Inject
TasksRepository tasksRepository;
```

How can it inject this without an @Provides for it anywhere?

If I try to use this same approach in my own app I get this error:

> cannot be provided without an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method

So I went looking everywhere in the Blueprints code but I can't see how they did it themselves. Is there some trick to it that allows them to not have an `@Provides`? It definitely builds so they've gotten around it somehow.

Someone has asked this same question on the actual github page but there are no answers at the time of writing. https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/issues/561.

I'm on the latest commit which at the time of writing is "082bd72d62472f9caadd2979046067fb928bbfef".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the repository you mentioned, Dagger 2 knows how to inject `TasksRepository` through the constructor being marked with `@Inject`. From the [source](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/082bd72d62472f9caadd2979046067fb928bbfef/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/data/source/TasksRepository.java#L83):

```
@Inject
TasksRepository(@Remote TasksDataSource tasksRemoteDataSource,
        @Local TasksDataSource tasksLocalDataSource) {
    mTasksRemoteDataSource = tasksRemoteDataSource;
    mTasksLocalDataSource = tasksLocalDataSource;
}
```

Since the constructor is annotated with `@Inject`, Dagger 2 will attempt to use the constructor to inject `TasksRepository` into consumers like `TodoApplication`.

Since `TasksDataSource` are already bound in `TasksRepositoryModule` there is enough information for Dagger 2 to perform injection without the burden of extra `@Provides` or `@Binds` methods.

Similarly, you can do the following:

```
class Foo {

   private final Bar bar;

   @Inject
   Foo(Bar bar) {
       this.bar = bar;
   }
}

class Bar {

    @Inject 
    Bar() {}
}

class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Inject Foo foo;

}
```

And Dagger 2 will be able to inject `Foo` inside `AppCompatActivity`. Why?

1. Dagger 2 knows how to construct a `Bar` object (through calling the empty constructor)
2. Dagger 2 knows that when creating instances of `Foo` it must use the constructor annotated with `@Inject` with the single parameter `Bar`.
3. There are no other dependencies for `Foo`, in other words the complete object graph is available.

Comment: Ok thanks David! After seeing this I've realised that my class with "@Inject" in the constructor didn't have everything provided so that's where the error is. I wasn't even looking at that yet since I was trying to find the "@Provides".